# Crashes when entering something other than a URL into a form and hitting enter

Tags: c#

I am developing a form that only allows URL input. But there is currently a serious bug.

```
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrl.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUrl.Text)) {

                WebBrowser.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
            }
```

The function of the above code is

・If enter any URL and press enter, the site page will be displayed.

・Disable the enter key when not typed or when a blank is entered.

**But,
If enter random letters or numbers other than the URL and press enter, it will be forced to exit.**

How do I disable the enter key when I'm typing random letters or numbers?

Comment: you need to use Uri class to verify whether the txtUrl.Text is valid uri, if yes, then navigate to it. otherwise, alert or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that txtUrl.Text is a valid URL.

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter && Uri.TryCreate(txtUrl.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out _)) 
{
    WebBrowser.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
}
```